# Multiple recurring log messages in Console. How to diagnose and correct?

Tags: mac, console, macos

I'm trying to clean up my Mac a bit, and in doing so I noticed a few repeating error messages in the console. The first goes off every couple of minutes:

```
coreaudiod[12074]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
coreaudiod[12074]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
```

Also, I'm getting a lot of:

```
sandboxd[14589]: ([14589]) WebProcess(14589) deny mach-lookup ATS Query Port 268
```

These are running a few every minute. Another one appearing a lot is:

```
WindowServer[115]: CGXSetWindowTransform: Invalid window 0x1925
```

I'm guessing these aren't connected? But might this be slowing down my mac? Any help on these welcome.  I'm on a Mac Pro, running OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 1):

The first ones go off whenever there is a sound emitted by the system, like copying a file.
The second is due to sandboxing.
The third I'm not sure, but it has to do with the GUI of the system.

Anyway, they are totally normal. The system generally logs a lot of stuff. I also have many of those logs, but it's in no way creating problems.

If you are worried it may take up a lot of space, you can use tools such as [MacPaw's Clean My Mac](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac), that can cleanup log files, caches, and so on. It can also aid the removal of apps, that can leave behind several files.

I got Clean My Mac with a bundle, and started to use regularly since then. Before I would always shun such apps, but I found this one quite nice. It remembers my settings, so I deselect specific locations, it won't clear those out in a manual check.

Comment: Thanks For this... Have seen Clean my MAc before, but like you I was unsure. I have given it a go, which has raised a new question... It found 'System Events' in the login items which link through to 'com.maintain.SystemEvents.plist' but thats as far as my investigation gets me...

Comment: You can check that file, it should be in /Library/LaunchAgents

When you look inside, you can probably see what the file is doing (if it's launching some command or something like that)